# SQL using "Left Join" to replace "not in" clause in a special case

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

As for simple tables, using "left join" and "is null" to replace "Not In" should be easy. However, in my case, it is not that straightforward.

Here is **tableA(Item, ReferenceID)**

```
Item(primary key)   ReferenceID
Chair                 123
Desk                  456
Sofa                  789
Bed                   111
```

Here is **tableB(StoreID, ReferenceID)**

```
StoreID(primary key)    ReferenceID(primary key)    
00001                   123                         
00001                   456                         
00002                   123     
00002                   456     
00003                   111
```

Note: TableB is a table indicating what items are excluded in which store.
So storeID=00001 has all items except for Chair (ReferenceID=123) and Desk(ReferenceID=456).

Given a **StoreID=00001**, how could I write a sql statement to achieve this purpose. More specifically, the result table should be:

```
Item(primary key)   ReferenceID
Sofa                  789
Bed                   111
```

Using "Not-in" Approach,which works correctly but slowly.

```
select * from tableA 
   where ReferenceID not in (select ReferenceID from tableB where storeID='00001'
```

Now I am trying not to use "not in" clause because of the slow performance.
I tried using "Left Join" but it doesn't seem to return what I want.

#1.

```
select * from tableA left join tableB
   on tableA.referenceID = tableB.referenceID
 where tableB.StoreID is null
```

This approach will exclude (bed, 111) because it exists in tableB

#2. try adding storeID to filter the result.

```
 select * from tableA left join tableB
         on (tableA.referenceID = tableB.referenceID and StoreID='00001')
 where tableB.StoreID is null
```

The result set is the same as the approach in #1, which excludes (bed,111).

**Questions:**

What is the correct SQL statement to achieve this purpose?

I am also open to accept other approaches that are not using "left join" as long as the performance is better than using "not in" clause.

**Edit:**

I simplified the actual SQL statements and situation above for helpers to more easily understand what I wanted to achieve, because I thought skipping the extra table and SQL statement do not matter.

Based on the comments below, I guess it matters now because the #2 approach seems to work correctly in the simplified situation above. Thus, I have to add one more table to reproduce the actual issue I have.

In fact, there is one more table. I join tableA and tableC and then left join tableB.

tableC (item, itemDescrption)

```
  Item(primary key)   itemDescrption
    Chair                 Very comfortable.
    Desk                  broken
    sofa                  large sofa (24*12)
    bed                   double size
```

As for approach #2 above, the actual statement is

```
select * from tableA 
    inner join tableC on tableA.item = tableC.item 
    left join tableB
         on (tableA.referenceID = tableB.referenceID and StoreID='00001')
 where tableB.StoreID is null
```

Comment: How is number 2 excluding `bed`?

Comment: (1) if a store does not miss any item then it would not appear in the report. You need a table with stores. (2) Syntax manipulation like this are rarely a good path to achieve performance

Comment: Because I thought I was going mad, I created your `tableA` and `tableB` on my box and ran your second query. It worked correctly.

Comment: @JNevill mad gentleman, I think your saying was correct. please see my new edit.

Comment: I think you mean `LEFT JOIN tableB ON ...`, right?

Comment: @JNevill. edited the typo. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, but the result is that your `INNER JOIN` to `tableC` yields the same result, which is exactly what you want. I assume there is something else here that is causing the issue that is not being shared in the sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your second attempt is the right way to go (although, I think `NOT IN` is not so bad, but if this is quicker then I'm all for it):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tableA;
+-------+-------------+
| item  | ReferenceID |
+-------+-------------+
| Chair |         123 |
| Desk  |         456 |
| Sofa  |         789 |
| Bed   |         111 |
+-------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM tableB;
+---------+-------------+
| storeid | ReferenceID |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       |         123 |
| 1       |         456 |
| 2       |         123 |
| 2       |         456 |
| 3       |         111 |
+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tableA left join tableB on (tableA.referenceID = tableB.referenceID and StoreID='1') where tableB.StoreID is null;
+------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| item | ReferenceID | storeid | ReferenceID |
+------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| Sofa |         789 | NULL    |        NULL |
| Bed  |         111 | NULL    |        NULL |
+------+-------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Updated for tableC inclusion (which has no effect on the results and still works as expected):

```
mysql> select * from tableA inner join tableC ON tableA.item = tableC.item left join tableB on (tableA.referenceID = tableB.referenceID and StoreID='1') where tableB.StoreID is null;
+------+-------------+------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
| item | ReferenceID | item | ReferenceID        | storeid | ReferenceID |
+------+-------------+------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
| Sofa |         789 | sofa | large sofa (24*12) | NULL    |        NULL |
| Bed  |         111 | bed  | double size        | NULL    |        NULL |
+------+-------------+------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Someone went madness and downvoted everyone here. I upvoted you. BTW, It seems the #2 approach is correct as you said. I guess I messed up with my testings.

Comment: I hope you figure out whatever it is that is causing the issue. I've got plenty of fake internet points so the -2 I got from the downvote isn't going to hurt... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try NOT EXISTS instead.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tableA tA
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                         FROM tableB tB 
                         WHERE tB.ReferenceID = tA.ReferenceID
                             AND tB.storeID = '00001');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `cross join` the stores with items and then `left join` on to this result.

```
select a.item,a.referenceID 
from tableA a
cross join (select distinct storeId from tableB) s
left join tableB b on b.referenceID=a.referenceID and b.storeId=s.storeId 
where s.storeId='00001' and b.referenceID is null
```

Comment: Why use CROSS JOIN + LEFT JOIN when a single INNER JOIN works?

Comment: I think someone got angry and downvoted everything. You've got my upvote for providing an alternate that produces data according to op's spec. I think they'll have a few options to run past EXPLAIN.

Answer (score -1):

Given the store id, this should be your query:

```
select a.* 
from tableA  A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.ReferenceID = B.ReferenceID
where A.storeID='00001'
```

Comment: It doesn't look correct to me. BTW, I didn't down vote your answer. Someone else did it.

Comment: I downvoted it because it is incorrect. The `referenceID` in `tableB` are items that should NOT be included for that particular store. This query will return "Chair" and "Desk" when the proper return would be "Sofa" and "Bed".